# How can I fill a div with other divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I am trying to create a sketchpad using jQuery (this is for a odin project assignment). The problem arises when trying to fill the canvas (the wrapper div) with pixels (pixel divs). It does not fill up properly. Here is my jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c3sq2jmb/2/

And the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.pixel {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid(16);
});


function createGrid(number) {
    for(var i = 0;i <= number*number;i++) {
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="pixel"></div>'); //adds pixels based on user command, default 16
    }
    $('.pixel').height($('.wrapper').height()/number); //adjusts the size of the pixels so that they fit the wrapper perfectly regardless of amount
    $('.pixel').width($('.wrapper').width()/number);
}

$('.pixel').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
);
```

Also, as a secondary question: on jfiddle the hover function works but when trying it in Chrome the pixels do not turn white when the mouse hovers on them. Any idea why?

PS: I know the program is not done by far, but I have hit a roadblock and I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by >It does not fill up properly.? - I.e. what does not fill up? and how is 'properly' supposed to work?

Comment: If you mean it's because there's an extra one at the bottom, it's because you've started counting from 0, but checked `<=` rather than just `<`, so you're getting an extra one created

Comment: Also - I'm on Chrome (40.0.2214.115 m), and they're turning white for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3sq2jmb/5/):

I have corrected the loop and the each pixel size assignment.

```
for (var i = 0; i < number * number; i++) {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div class="pixel"></div>');
}
...
$('.pixel').each(function () {
    $(this).height(height);
    $(this).width(width);
});
```

For the issue with Chrome, you need to define your method inside document ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  createGrid(16);

  $('.pixel').hover( function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you have an off by one error.

```
for(var i = 0;i <= number*number;i++) {
```

should be:

```
for(var i = 0;i < number*number;i++) {
```

Other than that it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You try do render 300px/16 which results in 18.75px (not full pixel value). The browser can't render it properly and you see the black fragments while hovering. With a 15 grid it works perfectly (300/15 = 20px box). And to handle the additional black box at the very end, try:

```
for(var i = 0;i < number*number;i++)
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3sq2jmb/4/)